# Find a power series representation for the function and determine the interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series

> Find a power series representation for the function $f\left( x \right)=\frac { x }{ 2{ x }^{ 2 }+1 } $ and determine of convergence.

I ended up with the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-2)^n x^{2n+1}$$

I don't know if that's right, and I also don't know what my interval of convergence would be.

$\left( -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  \right) $ perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. One may recall that
$$
\frac1{1+u}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n u^n, \quad |u|<1,
$$ giving, for $2x^2<1$,
$$
\frac1{1+2x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^n x^{2n}
$$ that is

> $$
> \frac{x}{1+2x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^n x^{2n+1}, \quad x \in \left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}2,\frac{\sqrt{2}}2\right).
> $$

Comment: But what about the x outside of the summation? I distributed that back to turn x^2n into x^2n+1. Wouldn't the +1 affect what my interval of convergence is? You divide both sides by 2, to gte x^2 < 1/2. You then square root both sides, and are left with what you already typed. But that +1..?